# No entry symbol found

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, ld

I am trying to compile a simple kernel.

There is a code of loader:

```
.text
.global boot
.code32

cli
call    main
jmp     .
```

Code of main:

```
int main(void){
    while(1){
    }
}
```

And linker scritp:

```
ENTRY (boot)

SECTIONS {
.boot   ALIGN(0x1000)   :   {   bootstrap.o(.text)   }
.text   ALIGN(0x1000)   :   {   *(.text)    }
.rodata ALIGN(0x1000)   :   {   *(.rodata)  }
.data   ALIGN(0x1000)   :   {   *(.data)    }
.bss    ALIGN(0x1000)   :   {   *(.bss)     }
}
```

So, when I am trying to link it together (`i586-elf-ld -T linker.ld bootstrap.o main.o`) it says that `cannot find symbol boot;`

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the symbol "boot" as label:

```
boot:
    cli
    call main
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot it. It solved one problem, now linker doesnt see main.